# Dynamically set apex:inputField required attribute while using CSS to hide/show field

Tags: apex, visualforce, validation, dynamic-visualforce

---

### How do I dynamically set the required property on apex:inputField while using CSS to show/hide said field in order to avoid the validation error upon saving a form that has said field as hidden AND required?

---

I have a basic use case to Show/Hide an apex:inputField based on the selection of a value from a picklist. If the picklist is 'x' we show the field, if it is 'y' we hide the field.

The dependent field has to be required.

The issue is that when an apex:inputField is required, but the CSS for it is "display: none", the field is still run through the validation logic and an empty value prevents the form from saving.

I have tried to set the required attribute via JavaScript, and also via Apex using an apex variable and a rerender, but the rerender resets the CSS properties and the code becomes too circular for my liking.

Here is some code samples, this is a pretty concise version:

```
             <apex:inputField value="{!Product.Type}" required="true" id="producttype" onchange="setProductFieldJS(this.value);" /> 
      <apex:pageBlockSection id="targetFieldSection" columns="2">
                    <apex:pageBlockSectionItem id="targetFieldSectionItem">
                        <apex:outputLabel style="display:none" value="Target" For="targetField" />
                        <apex:inputField style="display:none" id="targetField" value="{!Product.Target}" required="true" />
                    </apex:pageBlockSectionItem>
                </apex:pageBlockSection>

            function setCostFieldJS(val) {
              if(val == 'X') {
                  $("[id$=targetField]").show();
              } else {
                  $("[id$=targetField]").hide();
              }
            }
```

I will underscore that I was trying to use the rerendered for the field as a whole, and while the render toggle functionality was working, a bug was preventing the field from saving at random times, so in lieu of spending more hours searching for the bug I am deferring to this hybrid method for now.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Updated @AdrianLarson

Answer (score -1):

I think the following will work for you:

```
<apex:inputField style="display:none"
                 id="targetField"
                 value="{!Product.Target}" 
                 required={!IF(Product.Type == "X", true, false)}
/>
```

This should then only make the targetField required is Product.Type is "X"
I haven't tested this. It was just my first thought. It might not re-evaluate on change...